# I want to display category and subcategory list in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Maincategory1
     subcategory1
     subcategory1
Main Category2
     Subcategory2
     subcategory2

I want to display the above formet in categories and subcategories in wordpress.Anyone help me.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). You simply use

```
  <?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>
```

with the various arguments you want. The default value for hierarchical is '1': display child categories as sub-lists. Changing it to '0' displays them inline.

Comment: I am begginer of  wordpress explain briefly